# Script to load other .js scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-loading

I made a simple script to load other scripts into the page without worrying about caching. It's meant to be used by a considerable amount of people, so I would like it to be as clean as possible, and I would like your advice.

```
window.load_scripts = function () {
    var callbacks = {
        jqueryCallback: function (script_path) {
            $.getScript(script_path, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                if (jqxhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log(script_path + ' loaded correctly.');
                } else {
                    console.log(script_path + ' failed to load');
                }
            });
        },
        vanillaCallback: function (script_path) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = script_path + '?d=' + (new Date()).getTime();
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
    var callback;
    //if we don't have arguments, just return.
    //no scripts have to be loaded
    if (!arguments || !arguments.length)
        return;

    //if we have jquery, we will use $.getScript
    callback = window.$ ? callbacks['jqueryCallback'] : callbacks['vanillaCallback'];

    //loop through all scripts 
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var path = arguments[i];
        //just be sure that the argument is a string
        if (typeof path === "string") {
            callback(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

few suggestions...

- I would lose the jQuery part and stick to vanilla js for several reasons

  - jQuery's `getScript` doesn't add a script to the page like your vanilla example does, `getScript` actually uses `eval` to execute the code, which means any safe mode scripts will not be able to change any global state.
  - `$` is used by lots of libraries, not just jQuery. There's a real high chance you're going to get a false positive if you're only checking for `$` rather than `jQuery`.
  - The jQuery code is just unnessecary. Your vanilla code will always work, there is no benefit to using jQuery.
- Don't forget to add your onload callback so scripts that use this to include other scripts can use those other scripts after they have loaded.
- Declare your function. There is no benefit to doing `window.whatever = function(){};`. when you use `function whatever(){}` the function does not need to be defined at the top of the script, plus it's less bits.

Here's a function I wrote to include jQuery and stuff in userscripts, feel free to take it or parts of it.

```js
function loadScripts(scripts, appendTo) {
  appendTo = appendTo || "body";
  return new Promise((done) => {
    (function recurse(i) {
      if (undefined === scripts[i]) return done();
      let src = scripts[i];
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      if (script.readyState) { //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = () => {
          if (script.readyState == 'loaded' || script.readyState == 'complete') {
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            setTimeout(() => {
              recurse(++i);
            }, 1);
          }
        };
      } else { //Others
        script.onload = () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            recurse(++i);
          }, 1);
        };
      }
      script.src = src;
      document.getElementsByTagName(appendTo)[0].appendChild(script);
    })(0);
  });
}

// Example usage
loadScripts(["https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"]).then(()=>{
  $("body").append("loaded with jQuery");
});
```

Comment: Note that if you jump through all of the function calls that `$.getScript` makes - it actually does the same thing that the OP’s code does but removes the script element after it has executed.

Comment: glad to hear that. come to think of it, I was maintaining a pretty old code base when I ran into the issue with getscript using eval so that was likely with an old version of jquery.